# Php: how to access object individual elements

Tags: php

```
object(DateTime)#268 (3) {
  ["date"]=>
  string(19) "2010-02-02 00:00:00"
  ["timezone_type"]=>
  int(3)
  ["timezone"]=>
  string(13) "Europe/Berlin"
}
```

how to access the key "date" from the above, Thank you

Comment: I guess you want to start here: http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.php

Comment: What your problem? what your expected output?

Comment: `date` isn't a key, and the data you've dumped isn't an array. It's an instance of [the `DateTime` class](http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php), use the methods that are all well documented on php.net

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can access the date value in two different ways.

Number one: Use __toString()

```
echo $var->__toString();
// or
echo (string)$var;
```

Number two: Use the [DateTime format](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.format.php) method:

```
echo $var->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```